# C# console app web socket - clients not able to connect

Tags: c#, websocket, console-application

I created a C# console app web socket. It works and handles everything on my local machine, but now I have uploaded it on a real server so I can connect to it anytime.

But when I connect to the server endpoint, no connection is being made. I get this error:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws:// ... :8083/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

I have opened the port using:

```
netsh firewall add portopening TCP 8083 "NetBIOS TCP Port 8083"
```

and I've also tested to see if it's listening, and it is:

```
netstat -na | find "8083"
```

I repeat that the console app web socket was working on my local machine, but not working on the real server.

Any thoughts on this? Thank you!

Comment: Did you try a telnet to the remote server and the port from your machine?

Comment: Not really. I will enable that, thank you. But still, that error appears like in the case when I don't access the right IP address or endpoint. Locally I tried to access a different endpoint from the one that I set on the web socket, and I get the same error I mentioned above.

Comment: The telnet command will test if you really have access to the specific, port if the telnet doesn't respond you will not be able to send request.